# Could not find a part of the path of typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, service

Hello everyone here i have compiled a programme of typescript then it shows ms an error of the template of url what should i do any response?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeJ13.png)

Here is the content of my `app.component.html`

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 mt-4">
      <h1 class="text-center">Wallet List</h1>
      <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center">mwalletId</th>
            <th class="text-center">TRX_DATE</th>
            <th class="text-center">AMT</th>
            <th class="text-center">SIGN</th>
            <th class="text-center">TRX_LABEL</th>
            <th class="text-center">&nbsp;</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let wallet of wallets">
            <!--<td>{{ wallet.mwalletId }}</td>
            <td>{{ wallet.TRX_DATE }}</td>
            <td>{{ wallet.AMT }}</td>
            <td>{{ wallet.SIGN }}</td>
            <td>{{ wallet.TRX_LABEL }}</td>-->


            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm mr-2" (click)="showEditWalletForm(wallet)">Edit</button>

              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" (click)="removeWallet(wallet)">Delete</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="showAddWalletForm()">Add New Wallet</button>

      <div class="mt-4">
        <form *ngIf="walletForm">
          <h2>Add New Wallet</h2>
          <p>Mwallet_ID: <input type="text" name="mwalletId" [(ngModel)]="newWallet.mwalletId" /></p>
          <!--<p>TRX_DATE: <input type="text" name="TRX_DATE" [(ngModel)]="newWallet.TRX_DATE" /></p>
          <p>AMT: <input type="text" name="AMT" [(ngModel)]="newWallet.AMT" /></p>
          <p>SIGN: <input type="text" name="SIGN" [(ngModel)]="newWallet.SIGN" /></p>
          <p>TRX_LABEL: <input type="text" name="TRX_LABEL" [(ngModel)]="newWallet.TRX_LABEL" /></p>-->
          <p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-2" (click)="saveWallet(newWallet)">Submit</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" (click)="cancelNewWallet()">Cancel</button>
          </p>
        </form>
        <ul>
          <li *ngfor="let item of data">{item.TRX_DATE}</li>
          <li *ngfor="let item of data">{item.AMT}</li>
          <li *ngfor="let item of data">{item.SIGN}</li>
          <li *ngfor="let item of data">{item.TRX_LABEL}</li>
        </ul>

        <!--<form *ngIf="editWalletForm">
          <h2>Edit Wallet Details</h2>
          <p>Mwallet_ID : <input type="text" name="mwalletId " [(ngModel)]="editedWallet.mwalletId"/></p>
          <p>TRX_DATE: : <input type="text" name="TRX_DATE " [(ngModel)]="editedWallet.TRX_DATE " /></p>
          <p>AMT: <input type="text" name="AMT" [(ngModel)]="editedWallet.AMT" /></p>
          <p>SIGN: <input type="text" name="SIGN" [(ngModel)]="editedWallet.SIGN" /></p>
          <p>AMT: <input type="text" name="AMT" [(ngModel)]="editedWallet.AMT" /></p>-->
          <p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-2" (click)="updateWallet()">Submit</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" (click)="cancelEdits()">Cancel</button>
          </p>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: based on you images you have a bug in the app.html file. Looks like you forgot to end with a double `}` in your templatte binding. If anything share your app.html if you cannot find it.

Comment: I think the error message is quite clear in what it says. If you want anybody to be able to help you out, you should at least post the template  of `app.comonent.html` as code (not as an image)

Comment: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Please [edit] your question to include the text.

Comment: Please do not fill your post with repeated or nonsense content as a way to work around the quality filter. If the system prompts you to add additional explanation to your post, then do so. Don't attempt to bypass the warning. This is considered an abuse of the system, and may lead to your post being summarily removed and/or your account being sanctioned.  Please take the [tour], read up on [ask] and then [edit] your post with more details.

Answer (score 1):

```
<li *ngfor="let item of data">{item.TRX_DATE}</li>
<li *ngfor="let item of data">{item.AMT}</li>
<li *ngfor="let item of data">{item.SIGN}</li>
<li *ngfor="let item of data">{item.TRX_LABEL}</li>
```

You have to use double {{ item.AMT}} etc